# Comparing two vectors based on order and ranking?

Tags: statistics, correlation

What I want to do is compare the ordering of variables determined by the ranking of each variable.

For example:
Say, I have a rating system that is made up of 5 different ratings -

1. Excellent
2. Good
3. Moderate
4. Okay
5. Bad

so the vector representing this list would be 
$$v = \{excellent, good, moderate, okay, bad\}$$

Furthermore the ordering and ranking of these variables is determined by the frequency of the variables. Let's say, $a$ is
$$a = \{good = 156, excellent = 100, okay = 90, moderate = 50, bad = 10\}$$
$$a = \{2,1,4,3,5\}$$
So for $a$ good has rank, excellent has rank 2, etc.

For vector $b$
$$b = \{okay = 147,good = 100,exellent = 70,moderate = 60, bad = 20\}$$
$$b = \{3,2,4,1,5\}$$

My questions are:
1. Would a rank correlation be sufficient for this?
2. What about a case with vector $c$ where some of the variables have no frequency, so
$$c = \{excellent = 100, good = 30, moderate = 1, okay = 0, bad = 0\}$$
$$c = \{1,2,3,0,0\}$$
or even a vector like 
$$d = \{excellent = 5, good = 0, moderate = 0, okay = 0, bad = 0\}$$
$$d = \{1,0,0,0,0\}$$
where zero would represent that variable not having any ranking?

I would want to compare $a$ with $b$, $a$ with $c$ and $a$ with $d$

$\bf{ADD}:$ The rankings are based on the order of the vector $v.$
$v = \{excellent, good, moderate, okay, bad\}$
so
$v = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$
so $a$ becomes
$a = \{2,1,4,3,5\}$, etc.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is. What information do you want to get out of this comparison?

Comment: Basically, I want to be able to say if the ordering of a is similar to the ordering of b and what can I say about the similarity of a to c and d if there is information missing.

Comment: By similar, do you mean if they have the exact same order (given that a and b are order vectors)? Or are you trying to compare the frequency vectors by comparing their order? Also, what type of information would be missing?